# Does Postgres support virtual columns?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
ALTER TABLE formation ADD p varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DAT_FM -> '$.position') VIRTUAL;
ALTER TABLE formation ADD c decimal(12,3) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DAT_FM -> '$.c') VIRTUAL;
```

Does Postgres support to create a virtual column like MySQL?

Comment: Soon: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/generated-columns-in-postgresql-12/